# Software model design

Tags: c++, model

I was wondering how would i represent class functions and program flow when creating a design model. I've heard about design tools like UML but not sure how you actually represent functions and flow in diagram. could any give me an example? Is flow charting enough for this?

Answer (score 2):

In the UML you're doing the design, where you specify a high-level model of the project.

Functions belong to implementation. There contain many technical details which are irrelevant to your model, so you don't put them into the model.

You may create a list of class functions. Good choice of their names helps to understand what they are supposed to do. For some of them you may provide comments where you explain how you are going to implement them.

Of course you can represent some high-level interactions in the [sequence diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram).

Answer (score 1):

In UML what you are looking for sounds like an [Activity Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram). Like Oleg said, that's far more than detailed design, it begins to become a view on the implementation. If you have to show up how some complex internal logic works, how information is processed an activity diagram becomes useful. It is like flow charting but standardized, so I would prefer use that type of UML diagram instead of self made stuff.